# How to subset a DataFrame based on similar column names

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

How to subset similar columns in pandas based on keywords like A B C D. Now I have taken this as example is there any better way if new columns were given and logic should work.

```
df

A1 A2 A3   B1 B2 B3  C1 C2   D1 D2 D3 D4
1   a  x   1   a  x  3   c   7 d  s  4 
2   b  5   2   b  5  4   d   s c  7  d
3   c  7   3   c  7  1   a   x 1  a  x 
4   d  s   4   d  s  b   5   2 b  s  7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach can be to use `df.columns` in conjuction with [str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)

```
a_col_lst = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('A')]
b_col_lst = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('B')]

df_A = df.loc[a_col_lst]
df_B = df.loc[b_col_lst]
```

You can apply regex as well within `columns.str.contains`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pandas.Index.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.groupby.html)

```
groups = df.columns.groupby(df.columns.str[0])
#{'A': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3'], 
# 'B': ['B1', 'B2', 'B3'], 
# 'C': ['C1', 'C2'], 
# 'D': ['D1', 'D2', 'D3', 'D4']}
```

Then you can access data this way:

```
df[groups['B']]
#   B1 B2 B3
#0   1  a  x
#1   2  b  5
#2   3  c  7
#3   4  d  s
```

Keep in mind `groups` is a `dict`, so you can use any `dict` method too.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `filter` along with a regex pattern, e.g.

```py
df_A = df.filter(regex=(r'^A.*'))
```

You could also use `select` along with `startswith`:

```py
df_A = df.select(lambda col: col.startswith('A'), axis=1)
```

Comment: Getting: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'select'